# Python ProcessPoolExecutor How to lazily load processes on submit, instead of eagerly load a number of processes equal to max_workers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

If I create a `ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)`, but only `submit` 1 job, it will actually start 10 processes, not 1. The same is true if you instead create a `multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)`.

I assume it is eagerly preloading a number of processes equal to `max_workers` in order to minimize the start up time when `submit` is executed.

How can I disable this behavior, and only start up a process when `executor.submit` is invoked? Basically I want to lazily load these processes.

You can reproduce this behavior by executing the following code, and watching your process manager:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def task(i):
    print(f'task {i} started at {datetime.now()}')
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f'task {i} ended at {datetime.now()}')


def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        f = executor.submit(task, i=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main()
    time.sleep(20)
```

On Windows you can see that this will start 10 processes, instead of 1 process:

[image]

Likewise on Unix:

[image]

---

This eager loading behavior also occurs in `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=10)
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot lazily load processes on `submit` while using `ProcessPoolExecutor`. The reason is because `ProcessPoolExecutor` uses a `multiprocessing.Pool`, which eagerly loads all of the processes and cannot be changed.

If you would like to eagerly load the processes, then you will have to roll your own pool.